# AWS ec2 can connect to internal company DNS servers

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

Our company is using AWS to host internal projects servers with a VPC setup. Our Availability Zone can access internal resources through VPN.

How can I configure EC2 to know about internal DNS servers?

Answer (score 1):

A [DHCP Options Set](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonVPC/latest/UserGuide/VPC_DHCP_Options.html) can be associated with Amazon VPCs. It defines:

- Domain name servers
- Domain name
- [NTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_Time_Protocol) servers
- NetBIOS name servers
- NetBIOS node type

Therefore, if you wish to use your own DNS server, first turn off **DNS Resolution** for your VPC, then associate the VPC with a **DHCP Options Set** that points to your internal DNS servers.